# FullCalendar adding 2 events at once?

Tags: fullcalendar

As you can see in this image, I have 2 activities in the same time, but that happens only when I drop from an external place (The top right side). Is there any way to correct it?

[image]
Here is the code that makes that happen, I think:

```
drop: function(date, jsEvent, ui, event){
    var titulo  = $.trim($(this).html());
    var data = date.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var hora = date.format("HH:mm:ss");
    var fim = date.add(1, "h").format("HH:mm:ss");
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "cod_ajax/add_aula.php",
          data: "titulo="+titulo+"&inicio="+hora+"&fim="+fim+"&data="+data,
          cache: false,
          success:function(e){
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                  title: titulo,
                  color: e,
                  start: data+"T"+hora,
                  end: data+"T"+fim,
                }, false);
            $("#pop").hide(0);
            $("#pop").fadeIn("fast");
          }
    })
```

Comment: When an event gets dropped onto the calendar it renders - so your rendering after successful post is causing the event to appear twice. Also noticed that your function parameters for drop are also different from [the documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropping/drop/)  **function( date, jsEvent, ui, resourceId )**

Comment: @smcd I wrote `event` to try it out, still didn't work so, what can I do?

Comment: what do you mean by "it still didn't work". Did you change something from the code above? If so what did you change, and what was the result? Are you still having the exact same issue, or something different? Basically, as mentioned above, the event automatically gets rendered when you drop it on the calendar. There's no need to call renderEvent again after your ajax call. You can just remove that bit of code, I think.

Comment: @ADyson, I tried what you said, but the problem is, I want the colored one to be added, not the default one, because in the colored one, there is the information from that activity, so the `renderEvent` does that for me

Comment: as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropping/drop/, `this` in the context of the drop function will hold the DOM element that has been dropped. So after your ajax call I think you can simply set the background colour of the DOM element to the value of `e` instead. That should colour the already-rendered event for you.